# All Bullets Disapear when they Hit the Ball?

Tags: javascript

Hello i am new to java script, i am trying to make the bullets disappear when they touch the ball. But, all the bullets disappear, even the new ones. If you know how to make just the ones that touch disappear, pleas help!

```
    I didn't have them as a group and couldn't figure out how to make the ones hitting the ball disappear.

    World.frameRate = 120;
    //Guns
    var gun = createSprite(200,350);
    gun.setAnimation("gun");
    gun.scale = 1.2;
    //Bullets
    var bullet = createGroup();
    bullet.debug = true;
    //Ball
    var ball = createSprite(200,200);
    ball.setAnimation("ball");
    var health = randomNumber(1,600);
    //Walls
    var wall1 =createSprite(0,200);
    var wall2 =createSprite(200,400);
    var wall3 =createSprite(200,0);
    var wall4 =createSprite(400,200);
    wall1.setAnimation("wall");
    wall2.setAnimation("wall");
    wall2.rotation = 90;
    wall3.setAnimation("wall");
    wall3.rotation = 90;
    wall4.setAnimation("wall");

    //If Left Click Then fire bullet every 100 milliseconds
    setInterval(fire,100);
    function draw() {
      background("grey");
     gun.x = World.mouseX;
      gun.bounceOff(wall4);
        gun.bounceOff(wall1);    
  if (bullet.isTouching(ball)) {
      bullet.setVisibleEach(0);
      health = health -1;       
}
```

> i think this part is where it doesn't work ^
>   i don't know how to make this group command only get rid of the ones touching it and not all of the bullets in the group

```
      drawSprites();


      //Ball Counter
      fill("white");
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    textSize(25);
    text(health, ball.x, ball.y);
    }

    //Fire Function
    function fire() {
    if (mouseDown("left")) {
    var gunX = gun.x;
    var gunY = gun.y;
      bullet.add(createSprite(gunX, gunY-33));
    bullet.setAnimationEach("bullet");
    bullet.setVelocityYEach(-15);
    }
    }
```

> ```
>     Ball is to get hit by the bullets and the ones that hit it disappear
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using groups seems to be useful if you need to do the exact same operations on all of its sprites. However, in your case you want to treat each bullet individually. Instead of using a group, I would just use an array and then check if each of the bullets is touching the ball:

```
World.frameRate = 120;
//Guns
var gun = createSprite(200, 350);
gun.setAnimation("gun");
gun.scale = 1.2;
//Bullets
var bullets = [];
//Ball
var ball = createSprite(200, 200);
ball.setAnimation("ball");
var health = randomNumber(1, 600);
//Walls
var wall1 = createSprite(0, 200);
var wall2 = createSprite(200, 400);
var wall3 = createSprite(200, 0);
var wall4 = createSprite(400, 200);
wall1.setAnimation("wall");
wall2.setAnimation("wall");
wall2.rotation = 90;
wall3.setAnimation("wall");
wall3.rotation = 90;
wall4.setAnimation("wall");

//If Left Click Then fire bullet every 100 milliseconds
setInterval(fire, 100);
function draw() {
  background("grey");
  gun.x = World.mouseX;
  gun.bounceOff(wall4);
  gun.bounceOff(wall1);

  // Loop through each bullet to see if we can find one that is touching the ball
  for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
    var bullet = bullets[i];
    if (bullet.isTouching(ball)) {
      bullet.destroy();
      bullets.splice(i, 1); // We don't need to check if this is touching the ball anymore, so remove it from the array
      health = health - 1;
      break; // For simplicity, let's only detect one bullet touching per draw tick
    }
  }

  drawSprites();


  //Ball Counter
  fill("white");
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(25);
  text(health, ball.x, ball.y);
}

//Fire Function
function fire() {
  if (mouseDown("left")) {
    var gunX = gun.x;
    var gunY = gun.y;
    var bullet = createSprite(gunX, gunY - 33);
    bullet.setAnimation("bullet");
    bullet.velocityY = -15;
    bullets.push(bullet);
  }
}
```